# Solidity: Why use Initialize function instead of constructor?

Tags: architecture, state, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am doing audit smart contract where somebody prefer use initialize functions like this:

```
 bool private isInit=false;
 string private hello;
 
 function init(string _hello) public onlyOwner {
   hello = _hello;
   isInit = true;
 } 

 function doSomething() public {
   require(isInit, "Wait for initialize");
   ...doSomething
 }
```

Can you explain why the constructor was not used?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The initialize you wrote as an example is wrong, because it could be called by the owner several times, the purpose of the initializer (as well as the constructor) is to be called as the first function before using the contract, and never be called back a second time

However, initialize is used instead of the constructor when a contract that uses a **proxy** is published

***Why?***

In Ethereum, there are three major types of contract calls: **regular CALL**, **STATICCALL**, and **DELEGATECALL**.

When contract **A** makes a **CALL** to contract **B** by calling `foo()`, the function execution relies on contract **B**’s storage, and the msg.sender is set to contract **A**.

This is because contract **A** called the function `foo()`, so that the `msg.sender` would be contract **A**’s address and `msg.value` would be the ETH sent along with that function call. Changes made to state during that function call can only affect contract **B**.

[image: Example of call]

However, when the same call is made using **DELEGATECALL**, the function `foo()` would be called on contract **B** ***but in the context of contract*** **A**. This means that the logic of contract **B** would be used, but any state changes made by the function `foo()` would affect the storage of contract **A**. And also, `msg.sender` would point to the EOA who made the call in the first place.

[image]

how can we handle the ***constructor*** logic? The contract’s constructor is automatically called during contract deployment.

But this is no longer possible when ***proxies*** are in play, as the constructor would change only the implementation contract’s storage ***(Contract B)***, not the storage of the *proxy* contract ***(Contract A)***, which is the one that matters.

Therefore, an additional step is required. We need to change the constructor in a regular function. This function is conventionally called initialize or init, this function will be called on the proxy contract once both contracts have been published, so as to save all changes of state on the proxy contract ***(contract A)*** and not on the implementation ***(contract B )***

Comment: great explanation & diagram!

Comment: great explanation thank you. Could you also add a short explanation for static call to complete your post?

Answer (score 1):

[openzeppelin docs explains:](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/upgrades-plugins/1.x/proxies)

> **The Constructor Caveat**
>
> In Solidity, code that is inside a constructor or part of a global
> variable declaration is not part of a deployed contract’s runtime
> bytecode. This code is executed only once, when the contract instance
> is deployed. As a consequence of this, the code within a logic
> contract’s constructor will never be executed in the context of the
> proxy’s state. To rephrase, proxies are completely oblivious to the
> existence of constructors. It’s simply as if they weren’t there for
> the proxy.
>
> The problem is easily solved though. Logic contracts should move the
> code within the constructor to a regular 'initializer' function, and
> have this function be called whenever the proxy links to this logic
> contract. Special care needs to be taken with this initializer
> function so that it can only be called once, which is one of the
> properties of constructors in general programming.

[image]

In proxy implementation, we want the `proxy` contract to store all the state because if in the future implementation changes, we will still have access to all transactions or other state variables. But if your implementation has a constructor, the state inside the implementation will be stored inside the implementation instead of `proxy`.

`iNitialize` is just a function that set the state and it is called after the contract is deployed. when we calling it we initialize the state inside the `proxy` contract, but we need to make sure that this function is called only once.